# seekBar or progressBar to fast scroll a viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-progressbar, viewpagerindicator, android-seekbar

I have implemented a ViewPager that contains around 1000 fragment. Is there a component within the viewpager that allows fast-scrolling between pages ? Or do I need to implement a seekBar or progressBar with Listener to allow fast scrolling between fragments ?

I've been doing some searching and I found this code:   http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/11/examining-viewpager-3.html which allows to swipe 1 fragment/page    at a time using seekBar

PS:The ViewPager and the seekBar or any other component needs to be synchronized so when one changes the other changes too

Answer (score 0):

You can implement seekbar. Important, yours fragment must be a lite.. because it's maybe slowly.

```
final SeekBar sk=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);     
    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

       pager.setCurrentItem(progress);

    }       
});
```

Comment: I've already implemented this solution. The problem here is that the pager and the seekBar are not synchronized so when you move the seekBar the fragment changes but when you change the pager the seekbar does not change

Comment: For this, you need implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
Im method
 @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        seekBar.setProgress(position);
    }
and ignoring it's in seekbar listeners.

Comment: I've tried also adding that part but it's not an optimized solution to do that